# Subscription keys on Microsoft Cognitive Services

Tags: key, analysis, linguistics, azure-cognitive-services

**W**hen subsribing to Linguistic Analysis in Microsoft Cognitive Services, 2 subscription keys were generated. I am using the first one to connect to the service, but here comes the error code: *"Unspecified"*, which means *"Invalid subscription Key or user/plan is blocked."* (see error codes [here](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56ea598f778daf01942505ff/operations/56ea5a1cca73071fd4b102bb)).
Should I use both generated keys? How can I use them?
A small example of connection or analysis will be very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced that error for another API, when I used the copy button for either key. When I tried copying the key manually, it worked. Might have been coincidental though, as the first attemt was straight after generating the key, but the second attempt was later.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced something similar. Check if your are using the correct Endpoint in your code or try to "Regenerate your Key" (it might take up to 10 minutes until the new code is working).

[Azure - Overview (Endpoint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQtzI.png)

If you want to check your subscription key / location settings use the Microsofts "online" Linguistic API: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56ea598f778daf01942505ff/operations/56ea5a1cca73071fd4b102bb/console